# Seaborn barplot with axes that contain NaN

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a dataframe that has columns like these:

```
Electronics   Answers
Smartphone    Right
Computer      Right
Smartphone    Wrong
Smartphone    Wrong
```

What I want is to make a barplot with seaborn where the y axis would be the Electronics and the x would be Answers. When I tried to just plug it in

```
ax = sns.barplot(x='answers', y='electronics', fill ='electronics', data=df)
```

but I get ValueError: Neither the `x` nor `y` variable appears to be numeric.

How could I make a plot with the x axis having two columns, one for wrong and one for right, and the y axis being the electronics used in each of them?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I think [`seaborn.countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html), with `hue=Electronics` will be a better option for your data

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'Electronics': ['Smartphone', 'Computer', 'Smartphone', 'Smartphone'],
        'Answers': ['Right', 'Right', 'Wrong', 'Wrong']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

p = sns.countplot(x='Answers', data=df, hue='Electronics')
```

[image]